# warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, clang

I have a very simple C++ code statement `auto a = 12;`.

When I am compiling it with g++ in Linux using `-std=c++98` option I am getting an error as expected

`error: ‘a’ does not name a type`

But when I am compiling the same code with the same option in MacOS I am getting just a warning, but the code get's compiled fine.

`warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

But wasn't the whole point of `-std=c++98` to compile the code following C++ 98 standards? So the warning tells even though auto is a C++11 extension I am going to compile it for you?

Is there any option to force using `c++98` (or other standard)?

`g++ --version` prints
`Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)`
which is another weird thing by the way. So it is clang actually.

It's like asking `firefox --version` and getting `chrome 87.0.4280.163`

Comment: The compiler is right. Automatic type deduction wasn't added until the C++11 standard. Which came out 13 years after the (very first) C++98 standard. You can't use things that was introduced in a later standard, if you want to use an earlier standard. And why do you want to stay with the (now *ancient*) C++98 standard? You do know that we're up to the C++20 standard? And each update to the standard have made C++ so much better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the compiler is right about what? Yes auto is C++11 then why it is compiled with 98 standard?

Comment: Look at the compiler, look at their versions, look at their default options. Different compilers do different things. And different versions or the same compiler *also* does different things. And you should really treat all warnings as actual error that must be fixed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: C98 also had `auto`, but it meant something else. If it's compiling in C98 mode, it really ought to be using the C98 interpretation of `auto`.

Comment: @MooingDuck But `auto` couldn't be used without a type in C++98, so I think it's valid to accept a program, as long as the keyword is used in the new sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for suggesting me to use the latest language standard but my question doesn't have any connection to your answer. Yes I know there is a C++20 standard and extensively using it. I also know what features C++23 presumably will have. But that doesn't mean one should never ask questions about older standards.

Comment: For some reason `C++` compilers tend to be lax unless they are told to be *pedantic*. Which is wrong IMO. I would rather they were *pedantic* (if you specify a standard) and only lax if you specifically tell them to be lax. In a field that is usually as *exact* as *computer programming* that just seems more natural to me.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Except that _ancient_ versions of C would just assume random `auto` variables were all `int`, and some compilers carried that forward into C98 :(

Comment: @MooingDuck I believe legacy versions of GCC and some others even allowed those settings, like making all variables static by default and assuming K&R style default int. I think, Wacom C did.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, I didn't know that, my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On MacOS, you're using clang, not gcc. (If I recall correctly, MacOS provides "gcc" and "g++" as symlinks to "clang" and "clang++", respectively, so that scripts that assume gcc don't break.)

The two compilers just treat this case differently.

Yes, a compiler that conforms to the 1998 ISO C standard, as both gcc and clang attempt to do with `-std=c++98`, must diagnose that line.

As far as the standard is concerned, a non-fatal warning is a valid diagnostic. The standard doesn't require an invalid program to be rejected (unless it contains a `#error` directive).

If you want to strictly enforce C++98 rules and reject code that violates them, use `-std=c++98 -pedantic-errors` (with either gcc or clang).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Even though I think just printing an error would be more intuitive when no other option is given. If I am saying "compile this code using 98 standard" that means please compile the code using 98 standard unless other option is given.

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan Which is just what it did. The 1998 C++ standard requires a conforming implementation to "issue at least one diagnostic message" for a program that contains a violation of any "diagnosable rule". It doesn't require the implementation to reject such a program. By printing that non-fatal warning, clang met the standard's requirements. By specifying `-std=c++98 -pedantic-errors`, you can configure it to go beyond what the standard requires and reject programs with errors.

Comment: To be clear, I personally would have preferred the standard to require rejecting a program that violates a syntax or semantic rule, but at least most compilers have an option that makes them do that.

Comment: @KeithThompson  technically it's not violation forC++98, just means different thing.  `auto` means automatic variable in pre-ISO C and ISO C++98. It's opposite of function-local `static` and of `register`. You have had at type after it `auto int a = 12` but some permissive settings may allow default int. For purposes of compatibility with legacy code.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The `auto` keyword does have a different meaning in C++98, but `auto a = 12;` is a rule violation in C++98, because there's no type name. `auto int a = 12` is legal in C++98, but an error in C++11 (since the old meaning of `auto` was removed and with the new meaning it specifies two types -- which is a violation even if they happen to be the same type).

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors`, quoting [man g++](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++):

> -pedantic
>
> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C ++ ; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other
> programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C ++ . For ISO C, follows
> the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

Note: this is not meant as a feature to check strict standards conformance (see the rest of the description in the man page)

Comment: With `-std=c++98 -pedantic`, clang still prints a non-fatal warning. See my answer.